# Unable to get filename into alias

Tags: applescript, itunes

This applescript

```
tell application "iTunes"
set new_playlist to get first user playlist whose id is 20721
set nexttrack to (add(POSIX file ( get "/Users/paul/tmp/Music4/My Bloody Valentine - m b v - 2013 [FLAC][24-96][WEB]/09 Wonder 2.flac") as alias) to new_playlist)
set trackname to name of nexttrack
end tell
```

fails with

```
javax.script.ScriptException: The variable nexttrack is not defined.
```

I think the line before is the problem but I cant see what is wrong with it. (Note the starting point is the filenames are provided in unix / notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set songAlias to alias (POSIX file "/Users/paul/tmp/Music4/My Bloody Valentine - m b v - 2013 [FLAC][24-96][WEB]/09 Wonder 2.flac")

tell application "iTunes"
    set new_playlist to get first user playlist whose id is 20721
    set nexttrack to add songAlias to new_playlist
    set trackname to name of nexttrack
end tell
```

Comment: That might have made some difference Im not sure will mark as correct. But Ive realized in my example I'm using a flac file, and iTunes doesnt support flac.